# Why does calling d3.scale.linear.domain after data update squishes the scale?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3js for an interactive chart where you can enter data and the chart values will get updated. The chart is a basic 2d line chart that has {date, value} pairs. This is the code I'm using every time there's a new data update, to refresh the chart:

```
function fetchLatest()
{
    // get data from server
    $.getJSON('/dataset',
    function(data)
    {
        var data_etl = [];
        data_etl = data.map(function(d){
            return { x: parseDate(d.date), y: d.value };
        });

        var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundPoints([0, options.width - 97]);
        var yScale = d3.scale.linear();

        chart     
        .width($('.livechart').width())
        .height(300)
        .x(xScale.domain(data_etl.map(function(d){ return d.x; })));
        .y(yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data_etl, function(d) { return d.y;} )+1])); // PROBLEM LINE

        chart.replaceSeries(data_etl);

        chart.render();
    }); 
}
```

The issue is that while the chart appear perfectly the first time it is loaded, upon reloading (new data update), the y-scale gets completely squished (so the line becomes a flat horizontal line). I did some debugging, and pinpointed the issue to this line:

```
.y(yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data_etl, function(d) { return d.y;} )+1]));
```

If on *update* I don't call this line, then the chart is updated fine. However, if I call it, it causes the issue mentioned above. Does anyone know why this is happening?

**Edit** Per note from meetamit, there isn't enough information. I'm adding the chart object code as well:

```
function lineChart(insertionPoint) {
var _chart = {};

var tip = d3.tip()
    .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
    .offset([-10, 0])
    .html(function(d) {
        var tip_date = "<span style='color:#f78b20'>" + formatDate(d.x) + ": </span>";
        var tip_activity = d.y;

        return tip_date + tip_activity;
    });

var _width = 600, _height = 300,
        _margins = {top: 40, left: 40, right: 40, bottom: 40},
        _x, _y,
        _data = [],
        _colors = d3.scale.ordinal().range([
                '#33ccff', '#f78b20', '#99dc2a', '#57d4d3'
            ]),
        _svg,
        _bodyG,
        _line;

_chart.render = function () {
    if (!_svg) {
        _svg = d3.select(insertionPoint).append("svg") // <-2B
                .attr("height", _height)
                .attr("width", _width);

        renderAxes(_svg);

        defineBodyClip(_svg);
    }

    renderBody(_svg);

    _svg.call(tip);
};


function renderAxes(svg) {
    var axesG = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "axes");

    renderXAxis(axesG);

    renderYAxis(axesG);
}

function renderXAxis(axesG){
    // xAxis
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            //.scale(_x.range([0, quadrantWidth()]))
            .scale(_x)
            .orient("bottom")
            .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%m-%d"));        

    axesG.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", function () {
                return "translate(" + xStart() + "," + yStart() + ")";
            })
            .call(xAxis);
}

function renderYAxis(axesG){
    //yAxis
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(_y.range([quadrantHeight(), 0]))
            .orient("left");

    axesG.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .attr("transform", function () {
                return "translate(" + xStart() + "," + yEnd() + ")";
            })
            .call(yAxis);
}

function defineBodyClip(svg) {
    var padding = 5;

    svg.append("defs")
            .append("clipPath")
            .attr("id", "body-clip")
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", 0 - padding)
            .attr("y", 0)
            .attr("width", quadrantWidth() + 2 * padding)
            .attr("height", quadrantHeight());
}

function renderBody(svg) {
    if (!_bodyG)
        _bodyG = svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "body")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" 
                    + xStart() + "," 
                    + yEnd() + ")") // <-2E
                .attr("clip-path", "url(#body-clip)");        

    renderLines();

    renderDots();
}

function renderLines() {
    _line = d3.svg.line()
                    .x(function (d) { return _x(d.x); })
                    .y(function (d) { return _y(d.y); });

    _bodyG.selectAll("path.line")
                .data(_data)
            .enter() 
            .append("path")                
            .style("stroke", function (d, i) { 
                return _colors(i);
            })
            .attr("class", "line");

    _bodyG.selectAll("path.line")
            .data(_data)
            .transition()
            .attr("d", function (d) { return _line(d); });
}

function renderDots() {
    _data.forEach(function (list, i) {
        _bodyG.selectAll("circle._" + i)
                    .data(list)
                .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("class", "dot _" + i)
                .on('mouseover', tip.show)
                .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
                .on('click', function(d, i){ 
                    showTotalActivities(d.x);
                });

        _bodyG.selectAll("circle._" + i)
                .data(list)                    
                .style("stroke", function (d) { 
                    return _colors(i); //<-4F
                })
                .transition() //<-4G
                .attr("cx", function (d) { 
                    return _x(d.x); })
                .attr("cy", function (d) { 
                    //console.log("dy: " + _y(d.y));
                    return _y(d.y); })
                .attr("r", 4.5);

    });
}

function xStart() {
    return _margins.left;
}

function yStart() {
    return _height - _margins.bottom;
}

function xEnd() {
    return _width - _margins.right;
}

function yEnd() {
    return _margins.top;
}

function quadrantWidth() {
    return _width - _margins.left - _margins.right;
}

function quadrantHeight() {
    return _height - _margins.top - _margins.bottom;
}

_chart.width = function (w) {
    if (!arguments.length) return _width;
    _width = w;
    return _chart;
};

_chart.height = function (h) {
    if (!arguments.length) return _height;
    _height = h;
    return _chart;
};

_chart.margins = function (m) {
    if (!arguments.length) return _margins;
    _margins = m;
    return _chart;
};

_chart.colors = function (c) {
    if (!arguments.length) return _colors;
    _colors = c;
    return _chart;
};

_chart.x = function (x) {
    if (!arguments.length) return _x;
    _x = x;
    return _chart;
};

_chart.y = function (y) {
    if (!arguments.length) return _y;
    _y = y;
    return _chart;
};

_chart.addSeries = function (series) {
    _data.push(series);
    return _chart;
};

 _chart.replaceSeries = function (series) {
    _data = [];
    _data.push(series);
    return _chart;
};

return _chart;
}
```

Comment: Some notes: 1. The data updates are very minor updates (nothing huge that would render the overall chart flat), 2. if there's something wrong with the code for setting the domain, wouldn't the first time rendering also make the chart flat?

Comment: There is not enough information here. Are you doing anything to set the range of `yScale`? Maybe there's an issue there. Also, what do you get from `console.log(yScale.domain())` after you set that? If it's not the domain you expect, then either `data_etl` has unexpected large values, or there is/are some string(s) in there.

Comment: @meetamit - I'm new to d3.js so I'm not 100% sure, but to answer your questions: 1) no, I don't think I'm doing anything to set the range of yScale, 2) the yScale.domain before and after I call an update to the data (e.g., after chart.render() above) is the same ([0, 27] for my toy data set).